# How to Store Dropdown Values to DB in Flask

Tags: flask

I am using the below code in Flask to Store the Values in MySQL DB. I am only storing 2 values that are entered from a html page

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL


app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure db
#db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
#app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'P******'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'flaskapp'


mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Fetch form data
        userDetails = request.form
        name = userDetails['name']
        email = userDetails['email']
        type = userDetails['type']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, type) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", name, email, type([0],[1]))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'Save is Successful'
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/users')
def users():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    resultValue = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    if resultValue > 0:
        userDetails = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('users.html',userDetails=userDetails)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```

my HTML Page

[image]

I have a dropdown list. After entering the Name and Email and need to select the Type and store all the three values in DB.

Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to give a proper **id** in the HTML, like this:

```
<select id="type">
 <option selected value="1">New</option>
 <option value="0">Old</option>
</select>
```

Then read the data on the server side:

```
type = request.form.get('type')
```

Also I recommend to change the var name "type" to something more detailed.

Comment: Hi Thank You for your reply. Performed the suggested changes ... but encountering the below error..TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given.... Changed the column name as RequestType. Not sure if I need to perform any changes in the below code

Comment: Hi Thank You for your reply. Performed the suggested changes ... but encountering the below error..TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given.... Changed the column name as RequestType. Not sure if I need to perform any changes in the below lines of code                                                                                               RequestType = userDetails.get('RequestType')
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, RequestType) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", name, email, RequestType)

Comment: You're Wellcome. The call to execute is wrong, it takes 2 to 3 parameters as the error says. Read the documentation here and use the example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html